# Как сделать проверку if/else ширину блока в Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Нужно повесить toggle событие на элемент, который будет изменять ширину блока. То больше будет его делать, то меньше.

```
$(document).on('click', '.title', function() {
        if (('.content_review .review_item').width() = 200) {
            $('.content_review .review_item').animate({
                width: '400'
            }, {
                duration: 500,
                specialEasing: {
                    width: 'linear'
                }
            });
         } else {
        $('.content_review .review_item').animate({
            width: '200'
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            specialEasing: {
                width: 'linear'
            }
        });
    }                    
    });







    <div class="content_review">
            <div class="title">
    <div class="title_icon">
        <svg class="svg_icon svg_comment">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-comment"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="title_name">Reviews</div>
</div>
    <a href="#comment" class="btn_add btn_add-top js_modal">
        <span class="icon icon_add">+</span>
        Add Comments
    </a>
<div class="review_wr">
    <div class="review_item positive">
        <div class="review_header">
            <div class="review_name">
                <span class="icon review_icon">
                    <svg class="svg_icon svg_user">
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                Guest           </div>
                        <a href="/hyip/bpayment.biz" class="review_link">Bpayment.biz</a>
                        </div>
        <div class="review_body">
            <div class="review_text">Good company</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review_item positive">
        <div class="review_header">
            <div class="review_name">
                <span class="icon review_icon">
                    <svg class="svg_icon svg_user">
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                Guest           </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="review_body">
            <div class="review_text">Wow!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Полный код можете добавить?

Comment: @NikitaSmith это весь код на jquery

Comment: html добавь, чтобы видно было

Comment: `= 200` в `if`-е - это присваивание, а не сравнение. Поменяйте на `== 200` - может, уже и заработает. А ещё там `$` не хватает перед `('.content_review .review_item')`

Comment: @NikitaSmith тут в перемешку с php

Comment: @AndreyBal' в вопрос нужно добавлять итоговый HTML (который отображается в браузере), а не смесь из PHP и HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML не менял

```js
$(document).on('click', '.title', function() {
    var review = $('.content_review .review_item'),
        state = true, 
        width = 200;

    if( review.hasClass('small') ) {
      state = !state;
      width = 400;
    }

    review.toggleClass("small", state);

    $('.content_review .review_item').animate({
      width: width
    }, 500);         
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="content_review">
            <div class="title">
    <div class="title_icon">
        <svg class="svg_icon svg_comment">
            <use xlink:href="#icon-comment"></use>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="title_name">Reviews</div>
</div>
    <a href="#comment" class="btn_add btn_add-top js_modal">
        <span class="icon icon_add">+</span>
        Add Comments
    </a>
<div class="review_wr">
    <div class="review_item positive">
        <div class="review_header">
            <div class="review_name">
                <span class="icon review_icon">
                    <svg class="svg_icon svg_user">
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                Guest           </div>
                        <a href="/hyip/bpayment.biz" class="review_link">Bpayment.biz</a>
                        </div>
        <div class="review_body">
            <div class="review_text">Good company</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="review_item positive">
        <div class="review_header">
            <div class="review_name">
                <span class="icon review_icon">
                    <svg class="svg_icon svg_user">
                        <use xlink:href="#icon-user"></use>
                    </svg>
                </span>
                Guest           </div>
                    </div>
        <div class="review_body">
            <div class="review_text">Wow!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```